# Как работает оператор Like?

Tags: sql

Как работает оператор `Like`?

Как его правильно использовать?

Answer (score 7):

Сравнивает строки по маске. В маске можно использовать `%` и `_` - это спецсиволы. Процент - это любое кол-во символов, `_` - один.
Пример.
Маске `%тест%` соответствуют строки "1тест1", "простотест", "тест", но не "температура".
Маске `_тест` соответствуют строки "1тест", "2тест", но не "тест" или "тест1".

В самом запросе используется так

```
select * from mytable where my_field like '%q';
```

Чтобы выбрать все строки, где поле `my_field` заканчивается на `q`.

Comment: select * from mytable where my_field like '%q%';

Answer (score 2):

Оператор LIKE отличается тем, что будет работать быстрее substr(), т.к. чтобы сабстр работал быстро, для него понадобится индекс. А LIKE "ищет" и работает с тем, что есть.
Т.е. правильнее строить запрос так

```
select * from clients where name like 'Сидор%';
```

нежели

```
select * from clients where substr(name, 1, 5) = 'Сидор';
```

PS. Просто пример из практики. ;-)

PPS. Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет об SQL, то коротко - это поиск строк , которые удовлетворяют(содержат) заданному слову/фразе/регулярке. Более подробно [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179859.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от СУБД в предикате LIKE могут использоваться [регулярные выражения](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_predicate_like/page2.html).